# Starting a Xamarin.Forms animation (in loop) in the middle

Tags: animation, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am playing with the `Animation` class with a loop in the `Commit` call, and I'd like to spice it up:

> Can I start a (looped) animation **in the middle**?

Let's say I have the following code that loops an animation in 5 seconds:

```
// Time in seconds
maxTime = 5;

animation = new Animation(Animation_Handler, 
                          0.0, maxTime * 1000);
animation.Commit(owner: this, name: "test_animation", 
                 length: maxTime * 1000, 
                 repeat: () => true, easing: Easing.Linear);
```

This will have the handler `Animation_Handler` start with the argument `t = 0` and proceed being called until `t = maxTime * 1000`, then called again with zero.

Is it possible to start animating with a time `t` different from zero, *avoiding doing it by hand* with a time-shift in my animation code?

Comment: Do you mean changing the start time of the parameter in the Animation .ctor while it is running/repeating?

Comment: It would suffice to start with a different time, but looping always from `0.0` to `maxTime * 1000`, the period must remain the same.

Comment: ? The animation start/end times are times within the total animation time (`length` parameter of the Commit), are you looking at increasing the length and varying the start/end times within that time(length)? Or?

Comment: No, sorry I didn’t explain it well. The loop should always be in `[0, maxTime * 1000]`, but the time `t` used by the handle should start with any value within that range.

Comment: ? You have `start` and `end` within a `length`, what is `t`?

Comment: The event handles `Animation_Handler` has one parameter, a `double t` (time), as far as I can understand [from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.animation.-ctor?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Animation__ctor_System_Action_System_Double__System_Double_System_Double_Xamarin_Forms_Easing_System_Action_).

Comment: Ah...That callback contains the animated value that is determined by the start/end values mapped into the start/end times by an update cycle is determined by the rate in milliseconds (and of course the values have the easing curve is applied). so to change the value supplied as a param to the Action at each animation frame/step, you need to change the inputs (start/end/length times and/or the start/end value that is being animated).